# Querying 'DeletedEntry' using an id

Tags: api, contentful, contentful-management

The ContentManagement.Entry.delete webhook does not contain the entry fields.

Eg:

`{
  "sys": {
    "type": "DeletedEntry",
    "id": "{ID HERE}",
    "space": {
      "sys": {
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "Space",
        "id": "{SPACE ID HERE}"
      }
    },
    "revision": 1,
    "createdAt": "2017-08-18T09:57:26.226Z",
    "updatedAt": "2017-08-18T09:57:26.226Z",
    "deletedAt": "2017-08-18T09:57:26.226Z",
    "contentType": {
      "sys": {
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "ContentType",
        "id": "page"
      }
    }
  }
}`

Is there a way to retrieve the fields associated with the entry after it has been deleted? -or - Is there a method to query deleted entries so that we can get the associated field data?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to query deleted entries or retrieve their fields.

You can query unpublished entries through the management API, but once an entry is deleted it's gone and the webhook payload simply indicates the ID of the deleted entry, but all the corresponding content fields are lost.